# Progress bar with indeterminate mode on a button click doesn't work

Tags: java, netbeans, jprogressbar

I am using netbeans and this is the button click function. I want the progress bar to run as soon as I click on the button. The mode will be indeterminate because I am calling a class `WriteToFile` and it does the work for minutes in background and doesn't return any value.

```
private void createFileButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    String str = (String) selectTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    createFileButton.setEnabled(false);// Prevent more button presses
    String filepaths = fileChooserWindow.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    String selectType =(String) selectTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    WriteToFile writeOBJ;
    writeOBJ = new WriteToFile(filepaths,start,selectType);
    try
    {
        writeOBJ.selectType();
    }
    catch (SQLException | IOException  | RuntimeException ex)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: create a JProgressbar and set it in indeterminate mode and make it `setVisible(false)` by default and when function is called make the JProgressBar visible and hide it once everything is done

Comment: That doesn't work. I added jProgressBar1.setVisible(true) at start of the function and setVisible(false) at end. I think I need to use something similar to Backgroundworker in C#.

Comment: run it inside a Thread then

Comment: Can you explain with code? I have tried threading but I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work:

```
    jProgressBar1.setVisible(true);
    jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(true);
    Executor executor = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
       String str = (String) selectTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem();
       createFileButton.setEnabled(false);// Prevent more button presses
       String filepaths = fileChooserWindow.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
       String selectType =(String) selectTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem();
       WriteToFile writeOBJ;
       writeOBJ = new WriteToFile(filepaths,start,selectType);
      try
      {
       writeOBJ.selectType();
      }
      catch (SQLException | IOException  | RuntimeException ex)
      {
       System.exit(0);
      }
     jProgressBar1.setVisible(false);
   }
```